# Wordpress - Custom form won't redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, redirect, header

I have a custom PHP form that submits to an API. I am wanting to add this form to my sidebar of my Wordpress site. When I try the custom-form.php page by itself it works fine, submits to the API and redirects.

When I include custom-form.php into my sidebar.php then it doesn't want to redirect but it still submits to the API.

I know header needs to happens before anything else loads but how do I get it to load first if I am including it into the page?

```
header('Location: http://example.com');
```

Is there a better way to add my form to a Wordpress sidebar?

Code looks something like this:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST['submitted'])) {

   $errors = array();

    if (!empty($_REQUEST['name'])) {
    $name= $_REQUEST['name'];
    } 
    else {$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your name';}
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['submitted'])) {
  if (empty($errors)) {
      include 'myapi.php';
      header('Location: http://example.com');  
  }
}

//Rest of code....
//Output validation errors
//HTML Form
```

Answer (score 0):

Your index.php file would look like this.

```
ob_start();

/*content of your index.php here*/

ob_flush();
```

This will cause your Output buffering should start before anything sent/echoed to the browser.

Or you can try another solution by using default redirect function:

```
<?php wp_redirect( site_url() ); exit; ?>
```